# How can I stub/mock services in ASP.NET Core tests

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'd like to test some classes that are part of ASP.NET Web Api project. I don't need request-response integration tests via TestServer (though they're nice) but I want to keep my tests as close to "real thing" as possible. So I want to resolve my classes using services added in Startup but changing some of them by stubs/mocks on test basis (some tests need mocks, others - don't).

It was really easy to do in good old days when ASP.NET did not have internal dependency injection framework. So I would just call a class that registers all the dependencies to a container, then create child container for every test, change some dependencies to mocks and that's it.

I tried something like this:

```
    var host = A.Fake<IHostingEnvironment>();
    var startup = new Startup(host);
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    //Add stubs here
    startup.ConfigureServices(services);
    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    provider.GetService<IClientsHandler>();
```

It seems to work but I don't want to create the whole startup infrastructure for every test. I'd like to create it once and then create "child container" or "child scope" for each test. Is it possible? Basically I'm looking for a way to modify services outside Startup.

Answer (score 4):

Creating child scopes for every request can be done when configuring your HttpConfiguration by creating a custom `IHttpControllerActivator`.

This is for OWIN, but converting to .Net Core should be pretty simple:
https://gist.github.com/jt000/eef096a2341471856e8a86d06aaec887

The important parts are for creating a Scope & Controller in that scope...

```
var scope = _provider.CreateScope();
request.RegisterForDispose(scope);

var controller = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService(controllerType) as IHttpController;
```

...and overwriting the default `IHttpControllerActivator`...

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof (IHttpControllerActivator), new ServiceProviderControllerActivator(parentActivator, provider));
```

Now you can add your controllers to be created via the IServiceProvider with scoped Dependency Injection...

```
services.AddScoped<ValuesController>((sp) => new ValuesController(sp.GetService<ISomeCustomService>()));
```

To test your ValuesController within your unit tests, I would suggest using something like the Moq framework to mock out the methods in your service interfaces. For example:

```
var someCustomService = Mock.Of<ISomeCustomService>(s => s.DoSomething() == 3);
var sut = new ValuesController(someCustomService);

var result = sut.Get();

Assert.AreEqual(result, new [] { 3 });
```

Comment: I didn't have time to check it out but it looks promising. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just in case you would like to use the same `Web API Core` controllers and `DI` infrastructure for your `xUnit` unit tests (I would call them integration tests in this case), I would propose to move `TestServer` and `HttpClient` context to the base class implementing `xUnit` [`IClassFixture`](https://xunit.github.io/docs/shared-context.html).

In this case you will test `API` with all the services and `DI` configured in you your real `Web API Core`:

```
public class TestServerDependent : IClassFixture<TestServerFixture>
{
    private readonly TestServerFixture _fixture;
    public TestServer TestServer => _fixture.Server;
    public HttpClient Client => _fixture.Client;

    public TestServerDependent(TestServerFixture fixture)
    {
        _fixture = fixture;
    }

    protected TService GetService<TService>()
        where TService : class
    {
        return _fixture.GetService<TService>();
    }
}

public class TestServerFixture : IDisposable
{
    public TestServer Server { get; }
    public HttpClient Client { get; }

    public TestServerFixture()
    {
        // UseStaticRegistration is needed to workaround AutoMapper double initialization. Remove if you don't use AutoMapper.
        ServiceCollectionExtensions.UseStaticRegistration = false;

        var hostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseEnvironment("Testing")
            .UseStartup<Startup>();

        Server = new TestServer(hostBuilder);
        Client = Server.CreateClient();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Server.Dispose();
        Client.Dispose();
    }

    public TService GetService<TService>()
        where TService : class
    {
        return Server?.Host?.Services?.GetService(typeof(TService)) as TService;
    }
}
```

Then you can just derive from this class to test controller action this way:

```
public class ValueControllerTests : TestServerDependent
{
    public ValueControllerTests(TestServerFixture fixture)
        : base(fixture)
    {
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Returns_Ok_Response_When_Requested()
    {
        var responseMessage = Client.GetAsync("/api/value").Result;
        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, responseMessage.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

Also you can test the `DI` services:

```
public class MyServiceTests : TestServerDependent
{
    public MyServiceTests(TestServerFixture fixture)
        : base(fixture)
    {
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ReturnsDataWhenServiceInjected()
    {
        var service = GetService<IMyService>();
        Assert.NotNull(service);

        var data = service.GetData();
        Assert.NotNull(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's all well covered in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing#integration-testing-aspnet-core).

For integration tests, you use `TestServer` class and give it a `Startup` class (do not have to be the live startup, can also be `StartupIntegrationTest` or Startup with `Configure{Envrionment Name here}` / `ConfigureServices{Envrionment Name here}` method.

```
 var server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    // this would cause it to use StartupIntegrationTest class or ConfigureServicesIntegrationTest / ConfigureIntegrationTest methods (if existing)
    // rather than Startup, ConfigureServices and Configure 
    .UseEnvironment("IntegrationTest"));
```

To access the service provider, do

```
var server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseEnvironment("IntegrationTest")); 
var controller = server.Host.Services.GetService<MyService>();
```

For Unit tests you shouldn't use `IServiceCollection`/`IServiceProvider` at all, just mock the interfaces and inject them.

Comment: But I don't want to inject the mocked interfaces manually. I want to resolve the class using Services and I want to specify mocks for some of the interfaces before resolving a class.

Comment: Read the whole answer. Last paragraph is only for unit test, the majority of the answer is about doing integration tests and how they are supposed to be done. That's what TestServer is for and it's usage of Startup is made for. You don't have to use the request though, but as noted in the second code example, you can just access the IServiceProvider from the test server instance

Comment: So you assume we should create a new TestServer for every test? I just don't see how I can create one TestServer and change dependencies for every test (for some tests I need mocks, for others I don't).

Comment: You shouldn't change them, integration is about testing a specific configuration as a whole, which you can configure once per startup{environmentname} class (or configure{environment} method). i.e. you'd replace your DbContext configuration from production to in memory db in the "StartupIntegrationTest" class. When using xunit you can use class or collection fixtures to reuse an Testserver over several unit tests. When you want to test a class in isolation (w/o real dependencies), that's what unit tests are for.

Comment: There's no binary division between unit and integration tests. There's a huge grey area in between. If I have full-blown integration tests but for some cases I want to mock some dependencies (i. e. not to send real email), my tests are still integration tests.